# Can a script change the order of the pages within a sheets doc?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can I write a script to move these around? Such as sort them by most recently opened?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

you can change the order. See:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet?hl=en#moveActiveSheet%28Integer%29

determining the most recently opened might be another thing.

Comment: So, there aren't any events to listen when an active sheet changes?